# Run SSRS report for selected records from Javascript

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm

In Dynamics CRM 2011 we can filter the records in the report by selecting records on homepage grid.

How can I start this report from JavaScript filtered by selected records?

I know how to run a report from JavaScript by it's ID and related record type. But I would also like to pre-filter the result.

Answer (score 0):

I did once similar to this but using fetchxml report (not direct sql report). 
There is a blog post for this: http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/paulnieuwelaar/2011/12/18/Run_Fetch_XML_Report_on_Selected_Record_in_Dynamics_CRM_2011.aspx